# How to check weather JsonArray value available or not in android from webservice and get its data?

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-listview

I am working on learning JsonParsing. In that I have some `category_list` array. I parse data from that array and bind it to a `listView` in android. From that list I also again have to make an API call to that Web-service and check that `sub-category` are there or not ? If there is no sub category then it will be `product list`. i have tried as below but i have unable to parse from productList json

How to decide or give me any solution logic for it. My code is as below:

**main.java**

```
   package com.epe.yehki.ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.epe.yehki.backend.ServiceHandler;
import com.epe.yehki.uc.Header;
import com.example.yehki.R;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class SubCategoryActivity extends ListActivity {
    // SUB CATEGORIES...
    private static final String TAG_CAT_LlIS = "categories_list";
    private static final String TAG_CAT_ID = "category_id";
    private static final String TAG_CAT_NAME = "category_name";
    int flag;
    public Header header;
    public TextView title;
    // PRODUCTS....
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_LlST = "product_list";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_IMG = "image";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = "detail_description";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray subcategories = null;
    JSONArray products = null;
    public String catid;
    public String id;
    String name;
    JSONObject jsonObj;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> subcategoryList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/categories.php";

    private static String mainurl = "http://yehki.epagestore.in/";
    public String suburl = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
        this.header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.headersubcat);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent

        try {
            catid = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CAT_ID);
            name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CAT_NAME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("::::::::::::::MY CATEGORY ID::::::::::::::IN SUB "
                + catid);
        subcategoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        suburl = "http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/categories.php?"
                + TAG_CAT_ID + "=" + catid;
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::MY SUBCATEGORY URL::::::::::::"
                + suburl);
        title.setText(name);

        // Displaying all values on the screen

        ListView lv = getListView();
        new GetSubCategories().execute();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String catname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SubCategoryTwoActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CAT_NAME, catname);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CAT_ID, catid);

                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

    }

    private class GetSubCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubCategoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::SUB URL:::::::::::::::::"
                    + suburl);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(suburl, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    if (jsonObj.has(TAG_CAT_LlIS)) {
                        subcategories = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CAT_LlIS);
                        if (subcategories != null
                                && subcategories.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts
                            flag = 0;
                            System.out
                                    .println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::"
                                            + subcategories.length());
                            for (int i = 0; i < subcategories.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = subcategories.getJSONObject(i);

                                id = c.getString(TAG_CAT_ID);
                                String name = c.getString(TAG_CAT_NAME);

                                // tmp hashmap for single category
                                HashMap<String, String> subcategory = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                // value
                                subcategory.put(TAG_CAT_ID, id);
                                subcategory.put(TAG_CAT_NAME, name);

                                // adding contact to contact list
                                subcategoryList.add(subcategory);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        flag = 1;
                        products = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT_LlST);

                        System.out
                                .println("==========SIZE OF MY ARRAY PRODUCT LIST==================="
                                        + products.length());
                        System.out
                                .println(":::::::::::::::::::Product array:::::::::::::::"
                                        + products);
                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject p = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            String proId = p.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                            String proName = p.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                            String productImg = p.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_IMG);
                            String productDesc = p
                                    .getString(TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION);
                            System.out
                                    .println("::::::::::::::::MY PRODUCT DETAILS::::::::::::::"
                                            + TAG_PRODUCT_ID
                                            + "    PRODUCT NAME          "
                                            + TAG_PRODUCT_NAME
                                            + "   PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION      "
                                            + TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
                                            + "   PRODUCT IMAGE    "
                                            + TAG_PRODUCT_IMG);

                            HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            // product.put(TAG_PRODUCT_ID, proId);
                            product.put(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, proName);

                            product.put(TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, productDesc);
                            /*
                             * product.put(TAG_PRODUCT_IMG, productImg);
                             */
                            productList.add(product);
                        }

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * 
             * */

            if (flag == 0) {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SubCategoryActivity.this, subcategoryList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_CAT_NAME },
                        new int[] { R.id.name });
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SubCategoryActivity.this, subcategoryList,
                        R.layout.activity_single_produt, new String[] {
                                TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                TAG_PRODUCT_IMG }, new int[] {
                                R.id.product_label, R.id.product_desc,
                                R.id.iv_product_img });
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
if(jsonObj.has("name_of_the_field")){
    //yes
}
```

or

```
JSONArray mJSONArray = jsonObj.optJSONArray("name of array");
```

the method `optJSONArray("nameofarray")` will return a **null `JSONArray`** if it could not find the `JSONArray` with provided name.

Answer (score 0):

hmm there is one method to check if the key exists or not in json.
like if you have json array and you want to check if there is subcategory than 
call method on that array object.

Answer (score 0):

The `JSONObject` has method to check if the **key** exists in the JSON or not.

Quoting from the docs.

```
public boolean has (String name)    
//Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.
```

You can find the official doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29)